# Receive http response based on SQL script (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, api

I have an API endpoint that takes a SQL script in its body content to fetch the needed data from the server. The response JSON structure of this endpoint is as follow:

```
{
    "result": "the data resulted from the SQL execution",
    "totalrows: "the total number of data rows"
}
```

Because the data schema will be different based on the SQL sent, I created my data model for the JSON data deserialization as follows:

```
public class QueryResult
{
    public List<object> result { get; set; }
    public int totalRows { get; set; }
}
```

I send the request and I successfully receive the data back from the server:

```
public static async Task<QueryResult> ExecuteQuery(Query query)  
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
                                        {
                                            UseDefaultCredentials = true 
                                        });
            
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);
    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(AppSetting.url, content);
    var jsonResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QueryResult>(jsonResult); 
}
```

Sample of returned JSON (before deserialization):

```
{"totalrow":1,"result":[{"Name":"Ali","Age":35}]}
```

The I tried to cast the object based on my desired data model that I will use for my application but get below error message:

```
            NamesCollection= new List<Name>();

            var data = await ApiServices.ExecuteQuery(sampleQuery);

            foreach (var item in data.result)
            {
                NamesCollection.Add((Name)item);
            }
```

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type

How can I address this issue? I don't want to create an API call method for each data model and want to stick to one method where I can receive the response from it, deserialize it to a list of objects that I can then transform to which ever data type for the model I want to use.

Comment: can you share an example of the json returned by the api?

Comment: what is the definition of class `Name`? you need to provide a method to convert the JObject to that class. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators

Answer (score 0):

I managed to address this by using  `JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType`

```
foreach (var item in data.result)
            {
                Name name= new Name();
                name= JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(item.ToString(), name);
                NamesCollection.Add(name);
            }
```